Unable to use the Dapper Multimap when objects to map share a type (SQL restriction of having unique column names)
I am trying to bind my dapper queries to some models I have laid out. 4 of my objects use a User model as a type with and fields INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME etc. However in SQL Server, you cannot have a query with identical columns.
So in my Dapper multimap function I am not able to split on INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER 4 times to bind my data. Not sure how to solve this:
var certificationReviews2 = await connection.QueryAsync<ARMS_API.Models.CertificationReview>("select * from dbo.A2F_DMCP_0005_BrowseTest()", 
types: new[] { 
    typeof(ARMS_API.Models.CertificationReview), 
    typeof(State), 
    typeof(ARMS_API.Models.Program), 
    typeof(ActuarialFirm), 
    typeof(User), 
    typeof(User), 
    typeof(User) , 
    typeof(User)
    },
map: (objects) => {
    var certificationReview = (ARMS_API.Models.CertificationReview)objects[0];
    certificationReview.STATE = (State)objects[1];
    certificationReview.STATE.PROGRAMS.Add((ARMS_API.Models.Program)objects[2]);
    certificationReview.ACTUARIAL_FIRM = (ActuarialFirm)objects[3];
    certificationReview.ACTUARIAL_FIRM.CERTIFYING_ACTUARY.Add((User)objects[4]);
    certificationReview.PRIMARY_REVIEWER = (User)objects[5];
    certificationReview.SECONDARY_REVIEWER = (User)objects[6];
    certificationReview.DMCP_ANALYST = (User)objects[7];

    return certificationReview;
},
splitOn: "STATE_ID,PROGRAM_DD,ACTUARIAL_FIRM_DD,INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER,INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER,INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER,INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER");

Updated coding (4/2/24) :
                var certificationReviews = await connection.QueryAsync<ARMS_API.Models.CertificationReview>("select * from dbo.A2F_DMCP_0005_BrowseTest()", 
                types: new[] { 
                    typeof(ARMS_API.Models.CertificationReview), 
                    typeof(State), 
                    typeof(ARMS_API.Models.Program), 
                    typeof(ActuarialFirm), 
                    typeof(object), 
                    typeof(object), 
                    typeof(object) , 
                    typeof(object)
                    },
                map: (objects) => {
                    var certificationReview = (ARMS_API.Models.CertificationReview)objects[0];
                    certificationReview.STATE = (State)objects[1];
                    certificationReview.STATE.PROGRAMS.Add((ARMS_API.Models.Program)objects[2]);
                    certificationReview.ACTUARIAL_FIRM = (ActuarialFirm)objects[3];
                    certificationReview.ACTUARIAL_FIRM.CERTIFYING_ACTUARY.Add(new User {
                        INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER = (int?)(object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("CERTIFYING_ACTUARY_ID"),
                        FIRST_NAME = (string?)(Object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("CERTIFYING_ACTUARY_FIRST_NAME"),
                        LAST_NAME = (string?)(Object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("CERTIFYING_ACTUARY_LAST_NAME")});
                    certificationReview.PRIMARY_REVIEWER = new User {
                        INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER = (int?)(object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("PRIMARY_ACTUARY_ID"),
                        FIRST_NAME = (string?)(Object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("PRIMARY_ACTUARY_FIRST_NAME"),
                        LAST_NAME = (string?)(Object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("PRIMARY_ACTUARY_LAST_NAME")};
                    certificationReview.SECONDARY_REVIEWER = new User {
                        INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER = (int?)(object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("SECONDARY_ACTUARY_ID"),
                        FIRST_NAME = (string?)(Object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("SECONDARY_ACTUARY_FIRST_NAME"),
                        LAST_NAME = (string?)(Object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("SECONDARY_ACTUARY_LAST_NAME")};
                    certificationReview.DMCP_ANALYST = new User {
                        INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER = (int?)(object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("DMCP_ANALYST_ID"),
                        FIRST_NAME = (string?)(Object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("DMCP_ANALYST_FIRST_NAME"),
                        LAST_NAME = (string?)(Object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("DMCP_ANALYST_LAST_NAME")};

                    return certificationReview;
                },
                splitOn: "STATE_ID,PROGRAM_DD,ACTUARIAL_FIRM_DD,CERTIFYING_ACTUARY_ID,PRIMARY_ACTUARY_ID,SECONDARY_ACTUARY_ID,DMCP_ANALYST_ID");
            return (IEnumerable<CertificationReview>)certificationReviews;
        }        
    }

This still is not binding the user data. I have the spliton set correctly. I manually map but use object instead of dynamic and type cast it to the specified value. Still null/not mapping.

You're facing a problem with Dapper's QueryAsync method when trying to bind data from a SQL Server query to your models. Your query involves multiple instances of a User model, SQL Server does not allow for queries to return multiple columns with the same name, so you cannot use the same splitOn parameter (e.g., INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER) multiple times for different User objects.
To resolve this issue you could use SQL column aliases to ensure that each instance of similar data (e.g., each User model's INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, etc.) has a unique name in the result set. This involves changing your SQL query so that each field related to different User objects has a distinct alias. For example, prefixing or suffixing the column names with something indicative of their role or position (e.g., CertifyingActuary_INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER, PrimaryReviewer_INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER, etc.).In your Dapper QueryAsync call, use the splitOn parameter to specify the unique alias for the first column of each set of data that you want to map to a different object. This tells Dapper exactly where to split the data for mapping to your models. The splitOn parameter should match the first aliased column name for each object set coming from your modified SQL query.
sql query:
SELECT 
    cr.*, -- this fetches CertificationReview fields
    s.STATE_ID, s.OtherStateFields, -- State fields with aliases if needed
    p.PROGRAM_DD, p.OtherProgramFields, -- Program fields with aliases if needed
    af.ACTUARIAL_FIRM_DD, af.OtherActuarialFirmFields, -- ActuarialFirm fields
    ca.INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER as CertifyingActuary_USER_NUMBER, ca.FIRST_NAME as CertifyingActuary_FIRST_NAME, -- etc
    pr.INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER as PrimaryReviewer_USER_NUMBER, pr.FIRST_NAME as PrimaryReviewer_FIRST_NAME, -- etc
    sr.INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER as SecondaryReviewer_USER_NUMBER, sr.FIRST_NAME as SecondaryReviewer_FIRST_NAME, -- etc
    da.INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER as DmcpAnalyst_USER_NUMBER, da.FIRST_NAME as DmcpAnalyst_FIRST_NAME -- etc
FROM dbo.A2F_DMCP_0005_BrowseTest() -- Assuming this is your complex query or view

For the splitOn parameter, you now specify the first aliased column of each object to split on. just make sure these names match exactly what you've aliased them to in your SQL query.
  var certificationReviews2 = await connection.QueryAsync<ARMS_API.Models.CertificationReview, State, ARMS_API.Models.Program, ActuarialFirm, dynamic, dynamic, dynamic, dynamic, ARMS_API.Models.CertificationReview>(
    "your_modified_sql_here",
    (certificationReview, state, program, actuarialFirm, certifyingActuaryDynamic, primaryReviewerDynamic, secondaryReviewerDynamic, dmcpAnalystDynamic) => {
        // Map State, Program, ActuarialFirm as before
        certificationReview.STATE = state;
        certificationReview.STATE.PROGRAMS.Add(program);
        certificationReview.ACTUARIAL_FIRM = actuarialFirm;
        
        // Manually map each User, converting 'dynamic' to 'User' and assigning aliased fields to properties
        certificationReview.ACTUARIAL_FIRM.CERTIFYING_ACTUARY.Add(new User {
            INTERNAL_USER_NUMBER = certifyingActuaryDynamic.CertifyingActuary_USER_NUMBER,
            FIRST_NAME = certifyingActuaryDynamic.CertifyingActuary_FIRST_NAME,
            // map other properties similarly
        });

        // Repeat for primaryReviewer, secondaryReviewer, and dmcpAnalyst
        
        return certificationReview;
    },
    splitOn: "STATE_ID,PROGRAM_DD,ACTUARIAL_FIRM_DD,CertifyingActuary_USER_NUMBER,PrimaryReviewer_USER_NUMBER,SecondaryReviewer_USER_NUMBER,DmcpAnalyst_USER_NUMBER"
).ConfigureAwait(false);


In order for the columns to bind with the user model doesn’t the name have to match the models naming convention so it actually binds each value to the correct property in user? For instance how would dapper know this new primsry_internal_user_number should bind to internal_user_number since it can’t guess that.

So I actually tried changing the stored procedure aliases and attempted this method but again Dapper does not know how to bind each User model to alias column names.

@IrishRedneck yes, For Dapper to automatically map the columns from your query to the properties of your model, the names of the columns in the result set must match the property names of your model. When you use aliases in your SQL query to differentiate between the same fields belonging to different User objects, you must ensure that these aliases still map correctly to the properties of your User model. i have updated the code could give it a try

I have added your updates but because we went over the 5 type limit I had to use the unlimited approach with objects. So if I do the manual mapping. I cant use dynamic since the typeof() but i use object instead. However, this mapping is still not working and its also making me do explicit casting otherwise error. I also made sure aliases matched up , manual mappings as you noted, and the splits are matched up.

I have looped through and the values are there. I think .GetType().GetProperty("CERTIFYING_ACTUARY_ID") might be the wrong method to get the value? Any thoughts?

@Qiuzman When you are trying to access the properties using GetType().GetProperty("PropertyName") from an object, you're working with reflection, which can indeed retrieve property information. However, to get the property's value, you need to follow it up with .GetValue(objectInstance).instead of:(int?)(object)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("CERTIFYING_ACTUARY_ID")try using:(int?)objects[4].GetType().GetProperty("CERTIFYING_ACTUARY_ID").GetValue(objects[4], null)

I was able to get this to work. However, I have one other issue that I cannot tell if its just impossible or maybe there is a better solution. I have used the multimap and I have also just let the query map to dynamic as well just to test. My sql server takes 1 second to output 10k rows with 40 columns. Well thats great but it seems like it takes 20 seconds for this dapper query to run in my c# code. Is it just that sending 10k rows of 40 columns from a sql server to a backend takes a while?

@Qiuzman is your database hosted locally? materialization can be time-consuming for large dataset.Query Complexity can be also another reason behind the performance issue . To improve performance:  1)Optimize Your Query 2) If possible, limit the number of rows and columns returned by your query 3)Use asynchronous database calls 4) If you're processing a large dataset, consider using Dapper's streaming capabilities to process rows as they're received, rather than waiting for the entire dataset to be loaded into memory.5)try to reuse  connections or use a connection pool

It is hosted inside the same network but different vm or even possibly physical machine. I am realizing what I am doing is probably not the smartest which is doing the inner joins in sql server so it returns so many duplicates and rows/columns with redundant data. So I am thinking using QueryMultiple and binding to the models individually and looping through to map the model is best.
